# My Google Cloud Platform Website stopped working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google, bitnami

It may be a rookie mistake, but I don't know who else to turn to.

I have a Wordpress Bitnami, hosted on Google CLoud Platform.

It is the only instance on my account.

I was working on editing a document (nothing involving development code, just one-input text) and it suddenly stopped working.

I thought it was the internet, but it wasn't.

I was able to enter Google CLoud Platform, and in the information that I was able to rescue from the VM Instance I leave it below.

I already looked for information in the forum, but I don't understand much.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Edit:
The website
https://www.trasandinopropiedades.cl

```
Jan 5 04:51:07 wordpress-1-vm dhclient [294]: bound to 10.180.0.2 - renewal in 1702 seconds.

Jan 5 04:51:07 wordpress-1-vm systemd [1]: rsyslog.service: Succeeded.

Jan 5 04:51:07 wordpress-1-vm systemd [1]: Stopped System Logging Service.

Jan 5 04:51:07 wordpress-1-vm systemd [1]: Starting System Logging Service ...

Jan 5 04:51:07 wordpress-1-vm systemd [1]: Started System Logging Service.

Jan 5 05:13:07 wordpress-1-vm GCEGuestAgent [448]: 2021-01-05T05: 13: 05.0294Z GCEGuestAgent Error main.go: 181: Error watching metadata: Get http: //metadata.google.internal/ computeMetadata / v1 //? recursive = true & alt = json & wait_for_change = true & timeout_sec = 60 & last_etag = dbe41aa112fd874f: net / http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Jan 5 05:19:31 wordpress-1-vm dhclient [294]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.180.0.2 on ens4 to 169.254.169.254 port 67

Jan 5 05:19:31 wordpress-1-vm dhclient [294]: DHCPACK of 10.180.0.2 from 169.254.169.254

Jan 5 05:26:57 wordpress-1-vm dhclient [294]: bound to 10.180.0.2 - renewal in 943 seconds.

Jan 5 05:43:05 wordpress-1-vm dhclient [294]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.180.0.2 on ens4 to 169.254.169.254 port 67

Jan 5 05:43:40 wordpress-1-vm dhclient [294]: DHCPACK of 10.180.0.2 from 169.254.169.254
```

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. I just accessed your site using https://www.trasandinopropiedades.cl and everything seems to be working properly. Did you manage to fix the problem? If you run into a similar issue in the future, please take a look at the Apache (`/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log`) and PHP-FPM (`/opt/bitnami/php/var/log/php-fpm.log`) log files to try to get more information. Apart from that, please check if the machine is running into a performance issue by checking the output of this command (`free -m`)

Comment: Thank you very much. I try to many things. Finally, I STOP the instance VM on panel, and RESET the service. Then, I RESET apache, and work!.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain that this is the exact issue but I had something very similar happen to me recently whiles importing posts and images from one site to a staging site. In an attempt to find the solution I spent far too much time server monitoring and php upgrading etc. To my great embarrassment I realized the the issue was my storage running out. After upping storage for the account my issues stopped completely.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate to what Jonathan's answer. Go over to VM instances, then find your project. Clicking on "more actions" (three dots at the end of you instance). Click on "Stop". Then "Start/Resume". I didn't rest. WORKED FOR ME.

I opened Log directory: cd /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ and saw there was errors. so I did the above simple steps to fix the loading problem.

I had the same problem. I was trying to back up my site, I guess the instance was over loaded? Thanks.

WordPress Bitnami, hosted on Google Cloud Platform.